# log4j relative path to create log file

Tags: logging, log4j

Here is my log4j.properties file

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = D:/workspaces/Abhishek/Automation/MOPS/logs
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p  - %m%n
```

This does job for me only problem is the absolute path i have used. I want to use relative path now.

Below is my folder structure

```
--src
      --com
      --log4j.properties
--logs
     --log.out file
```

So my logs folder is outside the src folder where log4j.properties is situated?

How can i define relative path in such case. In case of jsp's we do it like `../webpages/page.jsp`.
How can it be achieved here ??

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I also have the same scenario (logs folder outside src).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass dynamic value like this

```
{logfileLoc}/logs/file.log.
```

in your case you want in the project folder itself so can have  -D (java argument or equivalent) param like -D logfileLoc =D:/workspaces/Abhishek , and you can access with variable `logfileLoc`. and consider changing this value for different environments.

Comment: doesnt this work in xml config file? its creating a new folder {logfileLoc} instead ..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I simply changed the following line

```
log4j.appender.file.File=logs\\myLogFile.log
```

And it worked fine relative to the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

On Linux with Tomcat and webapps this works:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/your.log
```

It's in `/your/tomcat/webapps/your_app.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`

And it puts the log file in `/your/tomcat/logs/` folder.

P.S. As I found out recently, it's not a good idea to use relative paths in this case. Because you can run the tomcat from different folders, not just tomcat_home/bin/ So, the best answer is by Piaget Hadzizi